# Bypassing cross origin policy using JQuery/javascript with no access to remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jsonp

I want to retrieve the following JSON using javascript:

https://www.gov.uk/api/organisations/skills-funding-agency

If I do a JsonP call I get:

callback=jQuery1113043552865949459374_1434727982051&_=1434727982052' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

If I do a JSON call I get:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is this at all possible? I've been googling for hours without any success. I've seen some PHP solutions but ideally don't want to have to install PHP to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a proxy curl request with your own PHP code to call the remote site. Then call your PHP curl proxy from your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wanna install PHP to do this, why did you tag with [php](/questions/tagged/php)? You need to use a **Server Side Script** like Proxy PHP file, that reads the content and executes it correctly.

`Proxy.php`:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    die(file_get_contents($_GET["url"]));
?>
```

And call it like this:

```
url: "proxy.php?url=http://gov.uk/blah/blah"
```